# Return node which parent is 'root' (level = 0)

Tags: php

I have the following code in PHP:

Mainly I want to get the node from a hierarchy which parent level is 0. Because a node which level is 0 is the root. So, I want to find the one that is before the root.

```
function getBaseParent($node)
{
  if ($node->level == 0) {
    return $node;
  }

  while ($node->getParent()->level !== 0) {
   $node = $node->getParent();
  }
  return $node;
}
```

The problem with this code is that it always returns the node which level == 0. I would like to return the node which parent level is 0, but I fail to see how to do that in my loop.

If the level of the node passed to the function is 0, I have to return the node itself.

Comment: What is `level` in the following call `$node->getParent(level)`

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. Edited.

Comment: So, `function getSomeParentLevel($node,$level=0){while($node->level > $level){$node = getParent($node);} return $node;}`, and call with `1` assuming levels increment reliably by 1? (In that case: I'd make `function getBaseParent($node){return getSomeParentLevel($node,0);}`, best not duplicate behavior.

Comment: Wrikken, I don't think I need to check if node-> level > level. I have edited my question to make it more clear of what I am looking for...I basically want to find the node which parent level is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expecting the node with level 1 has parent level 0. Then you just have to change the 0 to 1:

```
while ($node->level !== 1) {
    $node = $node->getParent();
}
return $node;
```

Comment: Then I don not think there's something wrong with your `while()`. Maybe `$node->level` is not an integer? You're doing a value comparison (==) in your if and a value&type-comparison (===) in your `while()`...

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
function getBaseParent($node)
{
  if ($node->level == 0) {
    return $node;
  }

  $grabnode = $node;
  while ($node->getParent()->level !== 0) {
    $grabnode = $node;
    $node = getParent($node);
  }
  return $grabnode;
}
```

Here in the loop, the current node is saved until the next iteration of the loop. Therefore on the last iteration it will hold the last node before the root node.

Comment: In this case, if we find a $node which $node->getParent()->level == 0, we would be returning $grabNode which would be not initialize.

Comment: If it ==0 then it wouldn't make it to the loop and the function would return in the initial if statement. EDIT: Just re-read your comment again, this comment doesn't answer your comment, sorry.

Comment: If ``($node->getParent(level) == 0)`` it wouldn't enter the first if and it wouldn't enter the while...

Comment: Yeah, I read it again and edited my comment. You would just have to add another if statement after the first to check for that scenario, and return what you want it to. Out of interest, What kind of tree is this? What are you using it for?

Comment: I have edited it with a solution. I just assign the $grabnode variable  as $node before the loop.